# Fail2ban not banning wrong private key file login attempt

Tags: fail2ban

I am trying to secure my server (ubuntu 18.04) using Fail2Ban version 0.10.2, I have noticed that there are no rules to ban ips that try to connect to the sever via SSH with fake private key files. The message on the auth.log for those login attemps are as follows:

```
Connection closed by authenticating user FAKE_USER HOST_IP port 13987 [preauth]
```

What I would like is to add a refex expresion to the sshd.conf file that bans such login attempts. I have been following some suggestions on some online artiles and I came up with this expression:

```
^Connection closed by authenticating user  <F-USER>.+</F-USER> <HOST> port \d+ \[preauth\]$
```

But it is still the ip's from which I try to use fake keys are not being blocked. Does anyone know how to ban ips when using wrong ssh private keys

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 spaces between 'user' and '<F-USER>' instead of 1.